How to remove min.css?ver= in WordPress theme?
I'm using WP Rocket on my site but I've been getting this message from PageSpeed Insights:

Reduce unused CSS Potential savings of 29 KiB

I would like to know how to remove it.
Example: https://example.com/wp-content/cache/background-css/example.com/wp-content/cache/min/1/wp-content/themes/voice/assets/css/min.css?ver=1714725364&wpr_t=1714736992
I tried this but it's not working.
function remove_theme_version_strings( $src ) {
    
    global $wp_version;
        
    $theme_version = wp_get_theme(get_template())->get( 'Version' );
    parse_str( parse_url($src, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query );

    if ( !empty( $query['ver'] ) && $query['ver'] === $theme_version ) {
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    }

    return $src;
    
}

add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_theme_version_strings' );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_theme_version_strings' );


Feels like you should entirely skip the call to that file, not just edit the URL.

Can you help me how to remove?

In wp-rocket plugin, there is option,related to minify css. Disable it and then there will be no css version like you mentioned.

Note that removing ?ver= from the URL won't really fix the "problem." PSI is telling you that that stylesheet is apparently not being used by the site (as Randy pointed out above.) Additionally, 29 KiB is not that big of a save and won't really improve your site's performance in a meaningful way.
